# Need Help in Python Variable updation (Pygame module)

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to increase my speed variable in my pygame code. But as i run this piece of code the speed remain 0.1 (if i press UP key) and 0 (else case). I am unable to debug this. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pygame
speed = 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
pygame.display.update()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if speed < 8 :
                    speed+=0.1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if speed > 0 :
                    speed+= -0.1                    

    pygame.display.update()
    print(speed)
    clock.tick(60)   

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Sould the speed increase while you keep UP pressed? Should it decrease if you release the key?

Comment: Exactly, the speed should increase from 0 to 8 while the UP key is pressed and should decrease (step of 0.1) to 0 if UP key is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the *event* KEYUP with the UP *key*. The event KEYUP occurs when a key (any key) is released. The event KEYDOWN occurs when any key is pressed down.

In you code, this means that when the UP key is pressed down, the speed is set to 0.1, and when the UP key is release, the speed is set to 0.0.

If you want the speed to *keep* increasing, and decreasing when a key is released, you should use a timer, like so:

```
import pygame
speed = 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
pygame.display.update()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, 20)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break 
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
                if speed < 8 :
                    speed+=0.1
            else:
                if speed > 0.1:
                    speed+= -0.1
                else:
                    speed = 0.0

    pygame.display.update()
    print(speed)
    clock.tick(60)   

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Adjust the delay in the set_timer to suit your taste. Also, note the addition to reset the speed to zero. Float operations are not completely exact, so repeated adding and substracting can lead to a 'zero' that is negative.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What i really want is to increase my speed variable up to 8.0, if i press the UP key (by 0.1 step). And similarly decrease it when I leave the UP key till speed becomes 0.

Comment: According to my logic, "if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN" condition will execute if any KEY is pressed, therefore i've written another condition "if event.key == pygame.K_UP", this will check the KEY that is pressed is UP key. and then I've applied the speed limit condition.
Similarly for KEYUP, Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to increase the speed while the UP key is pressed, upto a maximum of 8. Likewise, you want to decrease the speed while the DOWN key is pressed until the speed is 0. I will adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah the increasing part is true ,but what game requires is that, as I release UP key, the speed should go to 0 (in step of 0.1)

Comment: In that case, you can't use the keyboard repeat: you should add a timer to decrease the speed while the user is not doing anything. I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: Its working fine now. Thank you very much for your answer and precious time.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've seen this done is:

```
keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
    if speed < 8:
        speed += 0.1
if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    if speed > 0:
        speed += -0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris, But it does not seem to work for me..
Here is the link to my code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwgd600m8tvvz6p/testcase.txt?dl=0

Please do correct me if i am wrong somewhere.